# Rive + Jetpack Compose (Android)

Tags: animation, android-jetpack-compose, rive

For those new to [Rive](https://rive.app/), you probably know that Rive doesn't have support for Composables yet. Well, they don't have an official way of doing it as of today, but I found a way to do it.

Here is what I came up with, hope it helps:

```
/**
 * RiveComposable it's a custom composable made to show RiveAnimationView objects (xml)
 * in Compose. As of today, Dec 6th, 2023, Rive hasn't finish creating a composable that
 * would work with their XML objects; hence this composable.
 *
 * Rive is still working on fixing issues with the Preview functionality of Jetpack Compose.
 * Until that is fixed, I added [LocalInspectionMode] to replace the real animations with
 * an image of Rive's logo.
 * 
 * By LeviD Dec 2023
 */
@Composable
fun RiveAnimation(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    @RawRes resId: Int,
    autoplay: Boolean = true,
    artboardName: String? = null,
    animationName: String? = null,
    stateMachineName: String? = null,
    fit: Fit = Fit.CONTAIN,
    alignment: Alignment = Alignment.CENTER,
    loop: Loop = Loop.AUTO,
    contentDescription: String? ,
    updateFunction: (RiveAnimationView) -> Unit = { _ -> }
) {
    if (LocalInspectionMode.current) { // For Developing only, see documentation above for details.
        Image(
            modifier = modifier.size(100.dp)),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.rive_logo), // Use your own image here (.png) if you want.
            contentDescription = contentDescription
        )
    } else {
        val semantics = if (contentDescription != null) {
            Modifier.semantics {
                this.contentDescription = contentDescription
                this.role = Role.Image
            }
        } else {
            Modifier
        }

        AndroidView(
            modifier = modifier
                .then(semantics)
                .clipToBounds(),
            factory = { context ->
                RiveAnimationView(context).apply {
                    setRiveResource(
                        resId,
                        artboardName,
                        animationName,
                        stateMachineName,
                        autoplay,
                        fit,
                        alignment,
                        loop
                    )
                }
            },
            update = { updateFunction.invoke(it) }
        )
    }
}
```

**How to use it?**
Here is an example of how to use it with a listener.

```
RiveAnimation(
    resId = R.raw.animation_file, // Your rive animation as it is in the raw folder
    autoplay = true,
    animationName = "Timeline 1",
    contentDescription = "Some content Description"
) {
    val listener = object : RiveFileController.Listener {
        override fun notifyLoop(animation: PlayableInstance) {
            //Nothing to listen to
        }

        override fun notifyPause(animation: PlayableInstance) {
            //Nothing to listen to
        }

        override fun notifyPlay(animation: PlayableInstance) {
            //Nothing to listen to
        }

        override fun notifyStateChanged(
            stateMachineName: String,
            stateName: String
        ) {
            //Nothing to listen to
        }

        override fun notifyStop(animation: PlayableInstance) {
            enableButton = true // enableButton is a mutable variable in my composable
        }
    }
    it.registerListener(listener)
}
```

This piece of code will listen until the animation (Timeline 1) is over and then it will set the value of `enableButton` to true which in my code, it will enable my button "next".

Let me know if you have any questions, hope it helps.

I have tried many ways to implement Rive in Compose without breaking the Preview functionality and this is what works best for me and we use it in the company.

Comment: Thanks, this works well for our use so far.

Comment: I have a better implementation with listeners that works pretty well. I will post that later today. Glad that one works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated version of the previous code. This should handle listeners in a way that it get's them disposed as well. So no memory leaks. ;)
If no callback is passed to the function, no listener is created.

Hope it helps.

```
 @Suppress("LongMethod")
    @Composable
    fun RiveAnimation(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        @RawRes resId: Int,
        autoplay: Boolean = true,
        artboardName: String? = null,
        animationName: String? = null,
        stateMachineName: String? = null,
        fit: Fit = Fit.CONTAIN,
        alignment: Alignment = Alignment.CENTER,
        loop: Loop = Loop.AUTO,
        contentDescription: String?,
        notifyLoop: ((PlayableInstance) -> Unit)? = null,
        notifyPause: ((PlayableInstance) -> Unit)? = null,
        notifyPlay: ((PlayableInstance) -> Unit)? = null,
        notifyStateChanged: ((String, String) -> Unit)? = null,
        notifyStop: ((PlayableInstance) -> Unit)? = null,
        update: (RiveAnimationView) -> Unit = { _ -> }
    ) {
    
        var riveAnimationView: RiveAnimationView? = null
        var listener: RiveFileController.Listener? = null
        val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    
        if (LocalInspectionMode.current) { // For Developing only, 
            Image(
                modifier = modifier.size(100.dp),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.rive_logo), //any image
                contentDescription = contentDescription
            )
        } else {
            val semantics = if (contentDescription != null) {
                Modifier.semantics {
                    this.contentDescription = contentDescription
                    this.role = Role.Image
                }
            } else {
                Modifier
            }
            listener = object : RiveFileController.Listener {
                override fun notifyLoop(animation: PlayableInstance) {
                    notifyLoop?.invoke(animation)
                }
    
                override fun notifyPause(animation: PlayableInstance) {
                    notifyPause?.invoke(animation)
                }
    
                override fun notifyPlay(animation: PlayableInstance) {
                    notifyPlay?.invoke(animation)
                }
    
                override fun notifyStateChanged(
                    stateMachineName: String,
                    stateName: String
                ) {
                    notifyStateChanged?.invoke(stateMachineName, stateName)
                }
    
                override fun notifyStop(animation: PlayableInstance) {
                    notifyStop?.invoke(animation)
                }
            }.takeIf {
                (notifyLoop != null) || (notifyPause != null) ||
                        (notifyPlay != null) || (notifyStateChanged != null) ||
                        (notifyStop != null)
            }
    
            AndroidView(
                modifier = modifier
                    .then(semantics)
                    .clipToBounds(),
                factory = { context ->
                    riveAnimationView = RiveAnimationView(context).apply {
                        setRiveResource(
                            resId,
                            artboardName,
                            animationName,
                            stateMachineName,
                            autoplay,
                            fit,
                            alignment,
                            loop
                        )
                    }
                    listener?.let {
                        riveAnimationView?.registerListener(it)
                    }
                    riveAnimationView!!
                },
                update = {
                    update.invoke(it)
                }
            )
    
            DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
                onDispose {
                    listener?.let {
                        riveAnimationView?.unregisterListener(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    @Preview(showSystemUi = true)
    fun RiveComposablePreview() {
        RiveAnimation(
            resId = R.raw.testrive,
            autoplay = true,
            animationName = "Bouncing",
            contentDescription = "Just a Rive Animation"
        )
    }
```